# ruby on rails API returns empty body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a JSON api, but I`m having issues sending a response. I was told that my problem is in my controller.

Heres my code:

```
class Api::V1::PeopleController <  ApiController
  before_action :set_person, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /people or /people.json
  def index
    @people = Person.all
    render json: @people
  end

  # GET /people/1 or /people/1.json
  def show
    @person = Person.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render json: @person
  end
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the controller... what HTTP response status code are you receiving? What's your routes.rb look like? Any errors coming out of the rails console when you hit the endpoint? What endpoint are you actually trying to hit?

Comment: This was from my console:                                                                                                              `Started GET "/api/v1/people" for ::1 at 2022-06-23 20:16:44 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::PeopleController#index as */*
  Person Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people"
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/people_controller.rb:7:in index'
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 1079)`

Comment: this is my routes rb file:                                                                                                                         `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :people,:cars
    end
  end
end`

Comment: Do you have any Person in your database? You sure you are getting a blank body or []? I would expect you to be getting `[]`.

Comment: yea i seeded my db. I tested the api in postman and it works

Comment: Wait, it's working in postman? Where is it not working? If it is working in postman... it should be working everywhere. The browser might not be displaying it correctly?

Comment: in the browser i just get undefined. Theres nothing in the response body

Answer (score 0):

If in postman is working (as you say in the comments) your controller works fine.

The problem is mostly that the browser sends the header `accept: text/html` and your controller is (probably) only responding to `accept: application/json`

Comment: the weird thing is that my browser works fine with other apis

Comment: Maybe the other apis also respond to text/html. Check the logs after you perform the request from the browser to see if the application gets called.